# How could I create a two-part table with titles?

Tags: tables

can you help me create a table similar to this one?
[image]

I don't know how to do a similar thing, especially because I cannot find information about title for the two tabulars.

EDIT: I tried this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{11cm} |}
            \hline
             &  EfficientFace module \\ \hline 
            Stage1 & \makecell{Reshape \\ Conv1D [k=3, d=64, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU \\ Conv1D [k=3, d=64, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU}  \\ \hline
            Stage2 & \makecell{Conv1D [k=3, d=128, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU \\ Conv1D [k=3, d=128, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU} \\ \hline
            Predict & Global Average Pooling + Linear \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        
        \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{11cm} |}
            \hline
            Stage1 & \makecell{Conv1D [k=3, d=64] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [2x1] \\ Conv1D [k=3, d=128] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [2x1]}  \\ \hline
            Stage2 & \makecell{Conv1D [k=3, d=256] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [k=2] \\ Conv1D [k=3, d=128] + BN1D + ReLU + MPool1D [k=2]} \\ \hline
            Predict & Global Average Pooling + Linear \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        
        \caption{Architecture of the visual and audio modules}
        \label{tab:modules_architecture}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

And I got something like that:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example with just a one part table? I'm sure we could then help you with the rest.

Comment: Basic information how to write a table you can find in any introductory text about LaTeX, for example in https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf or in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. In this basis write your table and than tell us where you stuck. So far your question is of "do-this-instead-of-me" type, which will probably be closed soon.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Hello, thank you. I just edited my post.

Comment: You need to make full minimal examples not sniplets. We cannot compile sniplets. For example where does `\makecell` come from? Here you need to have the same size of the columns, so instead of the second `c|` you can try `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{10cm} |` if you have the `array` package loaded.

Comment: @daleif the command \makecell comes from the makecell package, it is useful to get multiple rows in a single cell

Comment: @link23 yes, and that is why it is more or less mandatory here for users to provide full minimal exmaples others can just copy and test as is. Then we do not need to guess

Comment: @daleif oh you're right, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick hack you could use a single table and insert your titles as rows in this table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|X|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{first title}\\
        \hline
               &  EfficientFace module \\ \hline 
        \multirow{3}{*}{Stage1} & Reshape \\ 
               & Conv1D [k=3, d=64, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU \\ 
               & Conv1D [k=3, d=64, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Stage2} & Conv1D [k=3, d=128, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU \\ 
        & Conv1D [k=3, d=128, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU \\ \hline
        Predict & Global Average Pooling + Linear \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{second title}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Stage1} & Conv1D [k=3, d=64] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [2x1] \\ 
        & Conv1D [k=3, d=128] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [2x1]  \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Stage2} & Conv1D [k=3, d=256] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [k=2] \\ 
        & Conv1D [k=3, d=128] + BN1D + ReLU + MPool1D [k=2] \\ \hline
        Predict & Global Average Pooling + Linear \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Architecture of the visual and audio modules}
        \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I centered the text of the cell created using the ``makecell`` command removing the ``[l]``, but I don't get how to center the text of the other cells (i.e. the first one stating "EfficientFace module")

Comment: @link23 Don't get me wrong, but are you sure centring is a good idea? I deliberately removed it as the text looked so unruly...

Comment: @link23 If you absolutely must torture your readers with centred text, you can use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` just as you did in your question.

Comment: ... also if you centre the text, like in the first image in your question, then people will see that the centre of `Architecture of the visual branch` and `EfficientFace module` don't match at all.

Comment: You are right. Thank you so much, I will left the text not centered :)

Comment: @link23 Great decision! If you now would also remove the vertical lines, your tables would look very professional! (you can read up about nice table layouts in https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs.pdf/0)

Comment: I will follow your advice and I will read this document as soon as possible, thank you again!

Comment: @link23 You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

With use of the `tblr` of `tabularray` package code for above table is concise and clear. Table is written as two table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
Architecture of the visual branch
\par\smallskip    
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,4-Z}, vlines,
             colspec = {c X[l,m]},
             cell{2}{1} = {r=2}{},
             cell{1,2}{2} = {c=1}{c},
            rowsep=3pt
             }
        &  EfficientFace module                         \\ 
Stage1  &   Reshape     \\[-1ex]
        &   {Conv1D [k=3, d=64, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU \\ 
             Conv1D [k=3, d=64, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU}     \\ 
Stage2  &   {Conv1D [k=3, d=128, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU \\ 
             Conv1D [k=3, d=128, s=1] + BN1D + ReLU}    \\ 
Predict &   Global Average Pooling + Linear             \\
    \end{tblr}
     
\bigskip
Architecture of the audio branch
\par\smallskip
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c X[l,m]},
             rowsep=3pt
             }
Stage1  &   {Conv1D [k=3, d=64] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [2x1] \\ 
             Conv1D [k=3, d=128] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [2x1]}   \\  
Stage2  &   {Conv1D [k=3, d=256] + BN1D + ReLU + MaxPool1d [k=2] \\ 
             Conv1D [k=3, d=128] + BN1D + ReLU + MPool1D [k=2]}     \\ 
Predict & Global Average Pooling + Linear                           \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Architecture of the visual and audio modules}
\label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```